# Power BI - Gateway to Azure SQL Database v Amazon RDS

Tags: powerbi, azure-sql-database, amazon-rds

I know for Power BI that you don't require the On-Prem Gateway to refresh data for Azure SQL Database.

Surprisingly I'm struggling to find information about Amazon RDS. Do you require the On-Prem Gateway to refresh data in the Power BI Service for Amazon RDS?

Comment: Can this blog https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Connecting-Power-BI-Service-to-Amazon-RDS-MySQL-data-source/td-p/1346768 be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDS is effectively a MySQL instance. MySQL requires a gateway.

Here is an extract from [the list of supported connectors and requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources).

You can see that Redshift does not need a gateway, however MySQL (RDS) does.

[image]